# Resetear Variable PHP luego de cada LOOP

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy haciendo un informe que tiene una columna llamada Saldos, que suma los valores de cada columna y los muestra. El problema es que la suma de los saldos es por cada iteración a cada ID de un proveedor dentro de una foreach PHP. En la imagen, se pueden ver los saldos en un cuadro ROJO.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora bien, como se aprecia en la imagen, los saldos se están sumando de manera correlativa, no respetando las condiciones de la consulta MySQL a excepción del primer proveedor. Puede haber 1 o muchos proveedores en el informe, pero si ven la imagen, en el segundo proveedor, el saldo del primer registro no vuelve al valor que le corresponde según la condición y si genero mas proveedores en dicho informa, los suma todos de manera correlativa.

Mi código:

```
<?php
$conexion->query("SET @saldo:=0");
$id_prov = array(312,313);
$id_fact = array(24); 
$codigo = 1104001;
?>

<table border="0" align="center" width="100%">
 <tr>
  <td width="116" align="center" style="font-size:7px; border-bottom: 0.5px solid black">COMPROBANTE</td>
  <td width="276" align="center" style="font-size:7px; border-bottom: 0.5px solid black">FECHA</td>
  <td width="65" align="center" style="font-size:7px; border-bottom: 0.5px solid black">FECHA VTO.</td>
  <td width="75" align="right" style="font-size:7px; border-bottom: 0.5px solid black">N DOC</td>
  <td width="75" align="right" style="font-size:7px; border-bottom: 0.5px solid black">CONCEPTO</td>
  <td width="75" align="right" style="font-size:7px; border-bottom: 0.5px solid black">TOTAL</td>
  <td width="75" align="right" style="font-size:7px; border-bottom: 0.5px solid black">ABONOS</td>
  <td width="75" align="right" style="font-size:7px; border-bottom: 0.5px solid black">SALDOS</td>
 </tr>
</table>
<?php
foreach ($id_prov AS $fila => $i){

$consulta = "SELECT 
t.folio, t.fecha_emision, t.fecha_vencimiento, t.n_doc, t.glosa, t.total, t.abonos, t.saldo, t.id_prov, t.rut, t.proveedor

FROM(
 SELECT

    fv.folio,
    fv.fecha_emision,
    fv.fecha_vencimiento,
    fv.n_doc,
    fv.glosa,
    dfv.total AS total,
    0 AS abonos,
    @saldo:=@saldo  + (dfv.total - 0) AS saldo,
    pr.id AS id_prov,
    pr.rut,
    pr.nombre AS proveedor

    FROM facturas_venta fv

    INNER JOIN det_fact_venta dfv ON dfv.folio_fact = fv.folio
    LEFT JOIN comprobantes_contables cc ON cc.id_fact = fv.id
    LEFT JOIN detalle_comprobantes dc ON dc.id_comp = cc.folio_comp
    LEFT JOIN proveedores pr ON pr.id = fv.proveedor

    WHERE fv.empresa = 2 AND dfv.codigo_total = '$codigo' AND fv.fecha_emision BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2021-11-30' AND pr.id = '$id_prov[$fila]'

    UNION

    SELECT

    fv.folio,
    fv.fecha_emision,
    '--' AS fecha_vencimiento,
    fv.n_doc,
    dc.concepto AS glosa,
    dc.debe AS total,
    dc.haber AS abonos,
    @saldo:=@saldo  + (dc.debe - dc.haber) AS saldo,
    pr.id AS id_prov,
    pr.rut,
    pr.nombre AS proveedor

    FROM facturas_venta fv

    INNER JOIN det_fact_venta dfv ON dfv.folio_fact = fv.folio
    LEFT JOIN comprobantes_contables cc ON cc.id_fact = fv.id
    LEFT JOIN detalle_comprobantes dc ON dc.id_comp = cc.folio_comp
    LEFT JOIN proveedores pr ON pr.id = fv.proveedor

    WHERE fv.empresa = 2 AND dfv.codigo_total = '$codigo' AND fv.fecha_emision BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2021-11-30' AND cc.id_fact IN('$id_fact[$fila]') AND pr.id = '$id_prov[$fila]')

    AS t ORDER BY t.n_doc ASC ";
            $resultado = $conexion->query($consulta);

            if ($resultado->num_rows > 0){
                while ($row = $resultado->fetch_array()) {

        $suma_total += $row['total'];
        $suma_abonos += $row['abonos'];

    ?>


    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" >
      <tr>
        <td width="80" style="font-size:10px"><?=$row['folio']?></td>
        <td width="90" style="font-size:10px"><?=$row['fecha_emision']?></td>
        <td width="80" style="font-size:10px"><?=$row['fecha_vencimiento']?></td>
        <td width="80" style="font-size:10px"><?=$row['n_doc']?></td>
        <td width="180" style="font-size:10px"><?=strtoupper($row['glosa'])?></td>
        <td width="90" style="font-size:10px; text-align: right">$<?=number_format($row['total'], 0, ',', '.')?></td>
        <td width="90" style="font-size:10px; text-align: right">$<?=number_format($row['abonos'], 0, ',', '.')?></td>
        <td width="90" style="font-size:10px; text-align: right">$<?=number_format($row['saldo'], 0, ',', '.')?></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

        <?php

                }
            }
       } ?>
```

Como resumen (los Saldos):

```
RESULTADO ESPERADO       RESULTADO OBTENIDO

   2.560.812                   2.560.812
  11.682.317                  11.682.317
  30.999.608                  30.999.608
  35.740.711                  35.740.711
  36.967.742                  36.967.742
  39.785.346                  39.785.346
 146.885.346                 146.885.346
 203.228.835                 203.228.835
 -----------                 -----------
  13.976.871                 217.205.707
  34.460.068                 237.688.903
  40.412.150                 243.640.986
  47.937.317                 251.166.153
  53.614.688                 256.843.524
  91.751.463                 294.980.299
 116.696.065                 319.924.900
 132.174.514                 335.403.349
 138.456.036                 341.684.871
 140.094.666                 343.323.501
```

Alguna ayuda, consejo u orientación con respecto al porque de esto?
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Luego de haberlas mostrado en la tabla, mandalas a 0...

Comment: como y en que momento del loop hago eso?

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurre que la solucion sería crear una nueva variable
SET @proveedor="&#$&#%";     /*un codigo de proveedor que no exista*/
luego dentro del SELECT
CASE
WHEN proveedor!=@proveedor THEN @saldo:=0, @proveedor=proveedor
END
el resto de las columnas.

nota: no tengo mucho conocimiento de la sintaxis de Mysql, no se si es posible definir dos cosas dentro del WHEN.
Saludos cordiales.